# ASP.NET MVC on IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have decided to deploy my MVC application on remote IIS. I have never deployed on IIS before.
My app already works locally. (It's made from classic MVC template with Entity Framework and just one *.cshtml page) So I published it and copied to the server. Then in the Sites I added it like this to the sites folder:
[image]

Then I set the directory browsing to enabled. And it works on the http://localhost/Home/ I see the Index.cshtml and the web.config.

Then If I click on the file I am getting this error:
[image]

So I looked in the Handler Mapping and tried the `Add Managed Handler...`to add anything for the `*.cshtml` files.[image]

But I don't know if this is exactly what I should do and if yes what Type to choose or if the Name: under the Type is also relevant. The DefaultAppPool is configured to .NET CLR Version v4.0.30319 with Integrated pipeline mode.

**EDIT1 (My controller):**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ScannerContext db = new ScannerContext();

    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Shelves shelves = new Shelves();

        /* Fill with data */
        shelves.shelfA1 = db.tblShelves
            .Where(x => x.name.StartsWith("A") && x.column <= 12)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.row)
            .ThenBy(x => x.column)
            .ToList();

        shelves.shelfA2 = db.tblShelves
            .Where(x => x.name.StartsWith("A") && x.column > 12)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.row)
            .ThenBy(x => x.column)
            .ToList();

        shelves.shelfB = db.tblShelves
            .Where(x => x.name.StartsWith("B"))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.row)
            .ThenBy(x => x.column)
            .ToList();

        shelves.shelfC = db.tblShelves
            .Where(x => x.name.StartsWith("C"))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.row)
            .ThenBy(x => x.column)
            .ToList();

        shelves.shelfD = db.tblShelves
            .Where(x => x.name.StartsWith("D"))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.row)
            .ThenBy(x => x.column)
            .ToList();

        return View(shelves);
    }
}
```

Comment: `.cshtml` pages are never called directly. These are just views for the MVC pipeline. It uses routes to show the correct view so for example `/home/index` will show the index.cshtml view of the home controller

Comment: `http://localhost/Home/Index` displays: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: If I should add another relevant info to find out the problem, I will, just tell me what you need.

Comment: @Dracke have you installed all the ASP.NET and IIS dependencies from windows features?

Comment: @Dracke that was just an example to explain how MVC works. We need to see more details about your MVC project ( Controllers / Views / ... ) to see how your routing works

Comment: @Mivaweb I have used the default routing which comes with the MVC template, haven't done anything with that.

Comment: Can you show us the controller you have created?

Comment: @user1666620 I don't know, I have just got access to this new server from our administrator.

Comment: @Mivaweb added, but the application works fine on my local computer so I guess there is no problem with the c# code itself.

Comment: @Dracke if you don't know, assume the dependencies are not installed. Go and find out.

Comment: @user1666620 I looked and everything seems to be installed.

Comment: @Mivaweb on the `http://localhost/Home/Index` the 404.0 seems to be handled by StaticFile handler, is this correct behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the type of the handler mapping to one below. The System.Web.Ui.Page.

And take a look to the directory order. I am sure it should looks like this below:

[image]

Add an application and set a physical path with the folder of your project!